# Limit of the function

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to +∞}(\sin{\sqrt{x+1}}-\sin\sqrt{x})$$
The answer is 0 but I don't understand how we get it.

Comment: @Dr.MV are you sure my friend? 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BSin(Sqrt%5Bx%2B1%5D)-Sin(Sqrt%5Bx%5D),%7Bx,0,100%7D%5D

Comment: No, I mean what I've written but maybe the answer is incorrect

Comment: Does this function have the limit?

Comment: Is 0 the correct answer?

Comment: $$
\sin(\sqrt{x+1})\approx\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right)\right) = \sin(\sqrt{x})\cos\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\right)+\cos(\sqrt{x})\sin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\right)\approx\\\sin(\sqrt{x})
$$

Comment: You can also use prosthaphaeresis formula $$\sin \alpha-\sin\beta=2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

First, notice that: $$\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leqslant|x-y|.$$
Then, notice that: $$\forall x>0,\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The Mean Value Theorem guarantees that there exist a number $\xi \in (x,x+1)$ such that

$$\sin(\sqrt{x+1})-\sin(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\xi})}{2\sqrt \xi}$$

Hence, using $|\cos(x)|\le 1$, we can write

$$0 \le \left| \frac {\cos(\sqrt \xi )}{2\sqrt \xi}\right |\le \frac1{2\sqrt x}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem, we obtain the coveted inequality

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left( \sin(\sqrt{x+1}) -\sin(\sqrt x)\right)=0$$

Comment: @mary Apology for the misleading comment, which I've since deleted.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Could anybody write the solution step by step?

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: this flood of downvotes for correct answer annoys me more and more...(+1) back...